# Rails - how to build a grid-like list of product page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, list

I want to build a product page where there are multi columns.  The problem I am running into using the following is that if I have an odd number of products then the column spills over to the next column.  I read that there [is a bug](http://zomigi.com/blog/deal-breaker-problems-with-css3-multi-columns/) with this using CSS 3.

My question is, how can I build this grid-like product list in rails?  I tried using table, but it just displays it in one column.  Thanks

```
div.four-column {
  -moz-column-count: 4;
  -webkit-column-count: 4;
  column-count: 4;

  -moz-column-width: 10em;
  -webkit-column-width: 10em;
  column-width: 10em;

  width: 910px;
}


<ul>
  <% @products.each do |product| %>
    <li class="box">
      <%= link_to product.name, product_path(:id) %></br>
      <%= product.price %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my suggestion would be to try a css framework for this kind of layout

[Grid960](http://960.gs/)

or

[Twitter bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/)

You can do what you want very easily.

Give it a try and tell me what you think.

Btw in your example, you show the code of your CSS for div with class four-column but below your erb seems to miss this div with this class definition?  all i can see is a div with class="box" !

Comment: I am currently using blueprint css now BUT Twitter bootstrap looks amazing.  I may just swap out and use that instead! Thanks

Comment: I am using it now for a side project and it is in fact pretty nice.  The grid layout is very easy to use <div spanX></div> if you wanna span your div on 4 column etc..  i switched from grid960 to bootstrap in no time.  let me know how it works for you.